# How reset serenity.property restart browser for specific test class

Tags: serenity-bdd

We restart browser after each @Test in test class.

I tried to set serenity property

```
serenity.restart.browser.for.each=story
```

but it affects all tests

How can i configure separate class, which will open browser before first @Test and keep it open until all tests in this test class are going. 
But do not touch all other test classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't extend your tests from base test

```
public class YourTest{
   @Managed(uniqueSession=true)
   public WebDriver driver;
}
```

If you run somewhere in CI and have BaseTest

```
public class BaseUiTest extends BaseTest{
   @Managed(uniqueSession=true, driver = "")
   public WebDriver driver;
}
```